# AWS SQS Delete Operation Behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Does the deletion AWS SQS message (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html) remove/acknowledge all messages that was earlier fetched by any of consumer?

I'm asking because I would like to make sure delete operation is not working in similar way to acknowledge described in (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/getting-started.html)

> In this mode, when a message is acknowledged, all messages received before this message are implicitly acknowledged as well. For example, if 10 messages are received, and only the 10th message is acknowledged (in the order the messages are received), then all of the previous nine messages are also acknowledged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acknowledgements are a **feature of JMS**. When you work with SQS directly, there are no acknowledgements sent to the producer of the messages.

If you require such acknowledgements you would have to develop [request-response system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/working-with-messages.html#implementing-request-response-systems) yourself, or use pre-existing solutions for that (such as with JMS).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response